# Segmentation fault and Valgrind not stacked address errors on a Trie Tree in C

Tags: c, memory, memory-management, struct, memory-access

I'm writing a Trie Tree in C, with these structs:

```
typedef struct sNode Node;
struct sNode {
    int word;
    unsigned int nsons;
    Node *next[26];
};

typedef struct {
     Node *root;
} Trie;
```

But I'm having a problem in this insert function:

```
int insert(Trie* trie, char word[]){
    int i=0, posiletter, contletters=0;
    char letter=word[0];
    Node *newroot;
    Node *newNode=NULL;
    Node **copyroot;
    Node *current=NULL;
    Node *Nodefather=NULL;
    Node verif;


    if (trie->root=NULL){
        newroot=malloc(sizeof(Node));   
        for (i=0; i<=25; i++) newroot->next[i]=NULL;
        newroot->nsons=0;
        newroot->word=0;
        trie->root=newroot;
    }
    copyroot=&trie->root;
    current=*copyroot;
    while (word[contletters]!='\0'){
        posiletter=(word[contletters])-'a';

        while( (current->next[posiletter])!= NULL ){ // Error in this line
            Nodefather=current;
            current=current->next[posiletter];
        }
        if ( (current->next[letter-'a']) == NULL ){
            newNode=malloc(sizeof(Node));
            //newNode=malloc(sizeof(Node));   
            for (i=0; i<=25; i++) newNode->next[i]=NULL;
            newNode->nsons=0;
            newNode->word=0;
            Nodefather->next[letter-'a']=newNode;
            Nodefather->nsons=(Nodefather->nsons)+1;

        }
        contletters++;

    }
    if  (letter=='\0') Nodefather->next[letter-'a']->word=1; //end of word
    return 1;
}
```

The function receives a pointer to the tree and an string. If the root of the Trie is NULL, it creates a node, after this, it searchs on the array next a free (NULL) position to store.

The problem is in this line:

```
while( (current->next[posiletter])!= NULL ){ // Error in this line
```

It gives me Segmentation fault error when I execute this, and this error on GDB:

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x0804883f in insert (trie=0x804b008, word=0xbffff230 "abcdef") at trie.c:97
97          while( (current->next[posiletter])!= NULL ){ // Error in this line
```

And using Valgrind this way: valgrind --tool=memcheck --leak-check=full --track-origins=yes ./trie It give me these errors

```
==3409== Invalid read of size 4
==3409==    at 0x804883F: insert (trie.c:97)
==3409==    by 0x80485FD: main (triet.c:36)
==3409==  Address 0x8 is not stack'd, malloc'd or (recently) free'd
==3409== 
==3409== 
==3409== Process terminating with default action of signal 11 (SIGSEGV)
==3409==  Access not within mapped region at address 0x8
==3409==    at 0x804883F: insert (trie.c:97)
==3409==    by 0x80485FD: main (triet.c:36)
==3409==  If you believe this happened as a result of a stack
==3409==  overflow in your program's main thread (unlikely but
==3409==  possible), you can try to increase the size of the
==3409==  main thread stack using the --main-stacksize= flag.
==3409==  The main thread stack size used in this run was 8388608.
==3409== HEAP SUMMARY:
==3409==     in use at exit: 4 bytes in 1 blocks
==3409==   total heap usage: 1 allocs, 0 frees, 4 bytes allocated
==3409== 
==3409== LEAK SUMMARY:
==3409==    definitely lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==3409==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==3409==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==3409==    still reachable: 4 bytes in 1 blocks
==3409==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==3409== Reachable blocks (those to which a pointer was found) are not shown.
==3409== To see them, rerun with: --leak-check=full --show-reachable=yes
==3409== 
==3409== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==3409== ERROR SUMMARY: 1 errors from 1 contexts (suppressed: 11 from 6)
Segmentation fault
```

I really appreciate any help. Thanks!

====Edit====
Values in the time of the crash:

```
(gdb) print current
$1 = (Node *) 0x0
(gdb) print current->next
Isn't possible acess the memory at the address 0x8
(gdb) print current->next[posiletter]
Isn't possible acess the memory at the address 0x8
(gdb) print posiletter
$2 = 0
```

===Edit2===
Other values requesteds:

```
(gdb) print contletters
$3 = 0
(gdb) print trie->root
$4 = (Node *) 0x0
(gdb) print trie->root->next[word[0]-'a']
Isn't possible acess the memory at the address 0x8
```

Comment: Could it be that you have an upper case or non a-z character in `word`?

Comment: No, just a-z and '\0' are read and I only used a-z in the tests, putting '\0' on the end of the string.

Comment: Also, does this happen the first time you invoke `insert` or after the tree has grown big? It helps a lot if you debug and see (and tell us) the values of the variables at the instance of crash.

Comment: Copyroot receives the address of the root of the tree. It happens in the first time, so I can't invoke it for the second time. I debugged again and put the values of the variables in the question.

Comment: What I mean is, `copyroot` is a local variable that just gets initialized and is never used, isn't it?

Comment: What is the minimal input word that causes the crash?

Comment: It would help you if you looked at other values as well. For example `contletters`, or `trie->root` or `trie->root->next[word[0]-'a']` etc and basically check all the tree to see if it is built correctly. Alternatively, you can put `printf`s around the code to log what is going on and check whether it goes according to your plans.

Comment: I created copyroot on an attempt to solve the problem, but made no difference. Any quantity of letters cause the crash, can it be one or more. I put the values of the variables requesteds on the edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ah how did I miss that!

Here is your problem:

```
if (trie->root=NULL)
```

should be

```
if (trie->root == NULL)
```

Note the `==`.

The way you have written it, you set `root` to `NULL` which evaluates to `false` and the root initialization is never done. You could figure it out by the fact that your gdb outputs `0x0` for `trie->root`

Comment: THANK YOU! It worked! I didn't notice that I put only one "=", I made a idiot mistake. I'm really glad for your help, thanks again!